# Asp label fix label position

Tags: asp.net

How do I make my label have an left margin at the same time retain its position ? I used the ff codes :

```
<asp:Label ID="qars" runat="server" Text="" style="padding-left: 4%"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="qaps" runat="server" Text="" style="padding-left: 9.9%"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="qaws" runat="server" Text="" style="margin-left: 11%;"></asp:Label>
```

When put different values, it adjust and not get aligned.

Comment: Please make your question more clear. Just adding padding left will obviously move the label text towards right.

Comment: for example my label1 content is firsttext and my label2 content sceondtext its position os fine like this one

firsttext secondtext

but when i changed the content its position are being not aligned ? like this

firstttext                         secondtext 

or this one

firsttextsecondtext

Comment: this should probably be tagged with CSS really, as it's CSS that affects positioning, not ASP.NET. Also, descriptions of positions are by their nature uncertain. Perhaps a picture of how it currently appears vs how you want it to appear would be informative.

Comment: Maybe try to put a `position:absolute;` in your `Style=`  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2008/03/11/absolute-and-relative-positioning-in-visual-web-developer-2008-designer/